# Codeigniter and mariadb missing one row

Tags: mariadb, codeigniter-3, php-7, hana

I selected 2k data from HANA DB and insert it to mariadb 10.1.19, but i keep missing one row (not the first or the last row).

here's my code

```
function sync_supplier($user = null){
    ignore_user_abort(true);

    set_time_limit(0);
    $this->db->truncate('suppliers');

    $dbjpa = $this->load->database('jpa',TRUE);

    $field = '"CardCode","CardName","CardType","GroupCode","Phone1","CntctPrsn","City","E_Mail"';
    $where = "'Y'";

    $result = $dbjpa->query('SELECT '.$field.' FROM JAVAPRIMA_ADI."OCRD" WHERE "frozenFor" != '.$where);

    $resultSupplier = $result->result_array();

    $count = 0;
    foreach($resultSupplier as $supplier) { 
            $data = array(
                'CardCode'=> $supplier['CardCode'],
                'CardName'=> $supplier['CardName'],
                'CardType'=> $supplier['CardType'],
                'GroupCode'=> $supplier['GroupCode'],
                'Phone1'=> $supplier['Phone1'],
                'CntctPrsn'=> $supplier['CntctPrsn'],
                'City'=> $supplier['City'],
                'E_Mail'=> $supplier['E_Mail']
                );

            $this->db->insert('suppliers',$data);
            $count++;
    }

    if ($result->num_rows() > 0){
        echo "num_rows : ".$result->num_rows();
        echo "<br>count : $count";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

here's the result (posted the image here but i was limited by 2 link, so i have to paste the text)

```
num_rows : 2827
count : 2827
```

and here's the phpmyadmin count

[phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh7Tp.jpg)

here's the HANA count

[hana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNfEv.jpg)

can someone please tell me what happened here ? that's one unlucky supplier, that probably won't get his money back...

Comment: That's a lot of code to do the one statement `INSERT INTO suppliers SELECT * FROM ocrd;`.

Comment: @RickJames that's a different db (mariadb & sap hana) on different server,

Comment: Then consider MariaDB Connect or FederatedX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a quick debug method... It appears that one of your rows may be causing an issue and is not being inserted...

To quickly test for that case you can perform a test on the insert... The result of the insert returns either True or False. So working with that you could try...

Replace

```
$this->db->insert('suppliers',$data);
$count++;
```

with

```
$count++;
if(! $this->db->insert('suppliers',$data)) {
  echo "The insert failed at count = $count <br>"; 
  // instead of the above echo use the var_dump or print_r
  // or use both for fun, but the var_dump is more useful!
  var_dump($data); // This is probably more useful
}
```

This simply checks the result of the insert and takes some action. You could even put an exit(); in here Just to find the offending row, if there is one.

Yes there are other ways to do this, but this would point you at what "might" be going wrong.

There are other things you could implement, but this is a quick "debug only check" just to give you some insight into what could possibly be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this TimBrownlaw.. i found what causing the problem.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)